How to realize references in the form [1],[2],[4]-[6] instead of [1,2,4-6]
All current settings related to refs are as follows
\usepackage[numbers, %super,
    sort&compress,
    square,
    comma,%
    ]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.2em}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\refsize}

\renewcommand\refname{{References}}```


Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Try sort option of natbib package instead of sort&compress.

I tried, but it didn't work. In the cite macro package, such a function can be realized with \def\citepunct{],[} and \def\citedash{]--[}. But I don't know how to do such a setup in natbib.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78527430/2777074

I'm sorry. Previously I didn't realize that these were two interoperable sites, I thought they were different.

@wushiqian What does this matter? If you post the same question on multiple independent site without linking them, you will still waste people's time.

This seems to work, but I'm not sure it won't have side-effects.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\bibpunct{[}{]}{], [}{n}{}{}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\NAT@space}{}}
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citexnum}{--\NAT@penalty}{]\mbox{--}[}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Abdelhamid:VLB92,Abdelhamid:VLB93,Abikoff:TEA88,Abrahams:TI90,Abrahams:TI91}

\cite{Abikoff:MI-8-3-64}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{texbook1}

\end{document}


I'd not do it this way, but you're the author and typesetter.

Agreed about the semantic difference you point out, but note that the OP asked for “[1], [2], [4]–[6]” not “[1], [2], [4–6]”.

This function can be realized (in natbib) by \setcitestyle{citesep={],[}}. However unfortunately it can only be realized for [4-6] instead of [4]-[6]. Also there is an unremovable space in front of the 2 in [1],[ 2].

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Changed according to the OP's preferences.

@wushiqian I modified the code to get [1], [2], [4]–[6]. But, frankly,I don't like the output at all.

Thank you very much for your solution. In fact I don't like the cumbersome and ugly style either.

@wushiqian If a journal or conference requires a style, it’s their job to provide the facility.
